# High PHP-FPM CPU load (Laravel, Nginx, PHP 8.2)

Tags: nginx, php, azure, php-fpm, azure-app-services

The server I am running has 4 vCPU's, 14GB of RAM, 250GB Storage. I get on a 1 minute interval average over a working day (7 hours) around 400-500 requests per minute.

I have increased the php-fpm settings to a max children of 40, start servers 10, min spare 10 and max spare 30. This is then configured to be on-demand.

Using `atop -C` I can see that most `php-fpm` processes are consuming 1-2% CPU. Most of the time 2/3 processes start to consume 66-89% CPU (pretty constantly).

When this becomes 4/5+ processes, the CPU goes to 350%^ and this is only under a stress of around 400-500 requests in a minute.

Is there a way I can indentify what is causing the php-fpm processes to consume such high CPU? I am using `pgbouncer` to pool SQL connections. It is a Laravel project and the SQL queries are not the best since it uses Active Record design patterns but to utilise over 80% CPU (extreemly regularly) over multiple processes tells me something is seriously unoptimised or wrong but from the nginx access log, I can't see anything that should be causing it during the peak CPU spikes - looks like casual requests, no exports etc..

Here is an example of what I see below, at least 3 processes are typically over 60% CPU all the time, request metrics are around 200 during this captured time so below average! Nginx access log shows nothing out the ordinary.

[image: Example of full process list]

Any help would be apppreciated or ideas on how I can debug this further. I am waiting to get the App Insights feature into production to attempt to isolate the issue using Azure App Insights.

The `php` processes are likely spawned from the `supervisorctl` service as 5 threads run for the queue workers.

I am using filesystem for sessions and after more research I can see in the nginx error log the same as the SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35891537/laravel-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded-in-vendor-symfony-finder

Output of `vmstat -w 5` for close to 2 minutes:

```bash
--procs-- -----------------------memory---------------------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- --------cpu--------
   r    b         swpd         free         buff        cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs  us  sy  id  wa  st
   3    1        60868       302760      1291416      8474048    0    0     3    94    3    2   7   9  83   1   0
   3    0        60868       305652      1291420      8474100    0    0     0   184 3032 11293  22  40  37   0   0
   6    0        60868       307456      1291420      8474152    0    0     0   102 3043 12776  26  40  33   0   0
   1    0        60868       309116      1291420      8474436    0    0     0   235 2904 13905  26  39  34   1   0
   2    0        60868       301588      1291428      8476964    0    0     0  1245 2935 15069  30  40  29   1   0
   3    1        60868       281128      1291432      8490560    0    0     0   196 2627 13892  31  40  29   1   0
   2    0        60868       303012      1291432      8484872    0    0     0   159 3759 13004  21  37  40   2   0
   9    0        60868       301080      1291436      8479384    0    0     0   151 3281 12728  24  41  35   0   0
   5    0        60868       313884      1291436      8478624    0    0     0    94 2999 13096  27  39  33   0   0
   2    0        60868       310636      1291444      8477260    0    0     0    70 3204 11980  24  36  40   0   0
   2    0        60868       309108      1291448      8477488    0    0     0  1542 2982 11453  20  29  50   0   0
   1    0        60868       305752      1291448      8477648    0    0     0    78 3036 9900  18  28  54   0   0
   2    0        60868       303772      1291448      8477816    0    0     0   133 2408 8044  14  18  67   0   0
   3    0        60868       295540      1291448      8477884    0    0     0   158 2482 8559  16  22  61   0   0
   1    0        60868       295684      1291452      8477888    0    0     0   105 2985 10358  20  28  52   0   0
   0    0        60868       295620      1291460      8477884    0    0     0    42 2352 7613  13  17  69   0   0
   1    0        60868       296772      1291464      8478040    0    0     0   134 2751 10899  14  19  67   0   0
   1    0        60868       279304      1291468      8495716    0    0     0   534 2801 9469  15  20  63   2   0
   3    0        60868       304536      1291472      8485952    0    0     0    59 3420 11658  17  22  59   2   0
   1    0        60868       297360      1291476      8480584    2    0     2    97 3079 11568  22  30  48   0   0
   1    0        60868       327652      1291476      8479708    0    0     0   220 2777 8600  16  27  56   1   0
```

I am unsure if these are accurate since the ASP uses "Virtual Disks" in Azure (as it is a docker container).

Comment: What's the question? PHP will cause CPU load when you give it tasks to do. If You want to avoid CPU load? Use caching. There's no other way. Good technique is employing [Varnish Cache](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/varnish/accelerate-wordpress-with-varnish-cache)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: It seems you use postgres, the equivalent of the command suggested above is this one :

```
postgres=# select * from pg_stat_activity;
```

If you suspect SQL to be overloaded and unoptimized request to take too long, you may be able to see it using this query as root on myqsl :

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

Looking at the time column you can identify long request or even hanged ones.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using an Azure App Service (ASP) and my PostgreSQL instance is another resource, there shouldn't be any pgSQL services running on here other than PHP connecting outbound via the PDO driver to run queries. The pgSQL runs at around  30% CPU and 25% Memory on another machine and the PDO driver connects to a PgBouncer pooler to allow cached connections for speed

Comment: I updated my question to include the full screenshot of all the processes running on the ASP rather than it cropped. My major concern is how the `php-fpm` processes are exceeding 70% CPU consistently under only a load of around 400 requests per minute as it has caused other processes like supervisorctl to crash

Comment: I mean, the high CPU load could be caused by some heavy or malformed request, my answer suggest to look after these request (if it is so...) and maybe point out the consuming process or component. IMHO there is no direct relationship between load observed on pgsql side and the one on php-fpm. A quick win should be to switch your governor from "dynamic"(if it's so) to ondemande, it could be surprising but the second one gives more performance.

Answer (score 0):

If "top" is showing php-fpm as using most CPU, then there's probably very little load coming from the DBMS (and subsequent comments confirmed this is elsewhere).

Looking at the stats here (while I'm not familiar with the version of top you are using) there seems to be *very* high memory usage even though pages aren't swapping much. You really need to reduce that. "around 400-500 requests per minute" is not a huge volume - particularly given the size of this server, but the capacity issue (which is causing the performance issue then getting in a feeedback loop) is about the number of requests being handled at any one time (arrival rate x response time).

Next on the list is checking that your opcache is configured and sized correctly.

If these don't resolve your issue then you'll need to start profiling the code. There is a cost to running the data capture for a profiler. You would be advised to split off a small proportion of the traffic to a second host and only run the profiler there.

Comment: Thank-you! Opcache is configured and I checked using the `opcache_get_status()` which yields a tonne of file lists that've been cached. The memory one I'm not sure is accurate in `atop` as when I run `free`, I see this: https://i.imgur.com/oHwTrPp.png which suggests I have 9GB memory available. I can run run a profiler on a second deployment slot but it seems this is something happening under high load (which I agree, is not that many concurrent requests)

Comment: You need to check how full opcache is / how often it is getting recycled

Comment: How would one go about achieving this? The above output seems like a lot of the cached files have a 0 hit but some do have a considerable amount of "hits" in its output

Comment: From used_memory, free_memory and last_restart_time returned by opcache_get_status